# Perl script for downloading a file not working

Tags: perl, file

This is a test script I wrote to download a file from an URL.

The URL must be a direct link to the download file, and depending on the time provided, the program will count down and download at the specified time.

The problem is, it works for smaller file (~kb), but when I try for big files it freezes.

```
my $url       = 'http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.2/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso';
my $file      = '//strawberry//myscripts//ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso';
my $starttime = '08.07.15 11:43:11';

my $nowtime  = time;    # time in sec since 1970
my $sTime    = 0;
my $sleepSec = 0;

# parsing the input (start) time
if ( $starttime =~ /^\s*(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})\.(\d{2})\s+(\d{1,2})\:(\d{1,2})\:(\d{1,2})/ ) {
    #   mktime(sec,min,hr,day,month,year)
    #   month (0..11); year = 0 => 1900 , year = 100 => 2000
    $sTime = mktime( $6, $5, $4, $1, $2 - 1, 100 + $3 );
}

print "\nNow, the time is         ---", ctime( $nowtime );
print "\nDownload will start at   ---", ctime( $sTime );

$sleepSec = difftime( $sTime, $nowtime );

if ( $sleepSec > 0 ) {

    print "I will sleep for $sleepSec seconds, and then download it. zzZ\n";
    my $num = $sleepSec;

    while ( $num-- ) {
        sleep( 1 );
        $| = 1;
        print "$num\r";
    }

    my $status = getstore( $url, $file );
    die "Error $status on $url" unless is_success( $status );
    print "Your file has been downloaded successfully.\n";
}
else {
    print "Shit I missed my starttime...\n";
}
```

Comment: where does it freeze at?

Comment: getstore() and is_success() are important for the issue but you didn't provide them.

Comment: It freezes at getstore

Comment: @ Сухой27 didn't provide them - I did not understand that

Comment: Сухой27 is not aware that they are defined in LWP and myriad Request and Response objects that are employed.

Comment: have you tried using strace?

Comment: What is `mktime`? And why do you have double slashes in your file path? I trust you know that Perl doesn't accept C-style comments? I have changed all the `//` comments in your Perl to hashes `#`

Comment: I did not use strace(I am on Windows); @Borodin I removed the # because it was formatting the text differently. mktime will convert date/time info to a calendar time